# Volley StringRequest gives always 500 results in object's array

Tags: android, android-volley

I try to get large response from an URL, but response is always giving no more than first 500 results (should be 10k).

**The code:**

```
private void volley() {
        // limit 10k
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "url?limit=10000",
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("Dataobject");

                        // Gives "Size: 500"
                        System.out.println("Size: " + array.length());



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, error -> {
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Even when limit is set to 501 it gives only 500.

Where are the limits ?

Will be grateful for any tip

Comment: that is probably a problem with a server, and has nothing to do with Android. Check the same API call using something else (Postman probably?)

Comment: that's it :) thanks